# Alinhamento de div's a direita

Tags: html, div, mpdf

Não estou conseguindo alinhar as div's a direita em meu relatório mpdf. Abaixo contém o print do relatório e o código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o código:

```
 </head>
    <style type='text/css'>
    .dados_principais {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
            margin-left: -1px;
            margin-right: -1px;
            margin-top: -1px;


           }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div>

                <div class='dados_principais' style='text-align: center;margin-top: 4px;border: 1px solid red;background-color:#dcdcdc;'> 
                    <b><span style='font-style: italic; font-family: arial;'>
                        Teste de robos</span>
                        </b>
                    <div>
                    <div class='dados_principais' style='text-align: left;width:17%; margin-top: -1px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff; '>
                        <div style='padding-left:3px; float:left; font-size: 9px;  '>1º Data</div>
                        <div style='padding-left:3px;'>
                        <span >". $data_inicio_ensaio ."<span>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class='dados_principais' style='width:41%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
                        <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura </div>
                        <span style='visibility:hidden;' >.<span>


                    <div class='dados_principais' style='border: 1px solid black;width:41.50%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
                        <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura </div>
                        <span style='visibility:hidden;'>.<span>
                    </div>  

                    </div>




<div style='width:100%;text-align: left; margin-top: -1px;border: 1px solid blue;'>
                <div class='dados_principais' style='border: 1px solid black;width:17%; margin-top: -1px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff; '>
                    <div style='padding-left:3px; float:left; font-size: 9px;  '>2º Data</div>
                    <span >". $data_inicio_ensaio2 ."<span>
                     </div>


                <div class='dados_principais' style='width:39%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
                <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura</div>
                <span style='visibility:hidden;' >.<span>
            </div>  

                <div class='dados_principais' style='border: 1px solid black;width:39%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
                <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura </div>
                <span style='visibility:hidden;'>.<span>
            </div>  
            </div>
```

Eu preciso que as divs(os dois campos assinatura) que estão ao lado do campo "1º Data", fiquem ao lado conforme as divs que estão na segunda linha "2º Data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulo o seu código tinha uma série de tag abertas, tinha div fechada no lugar errado etc...

Segue o seu código com a correção, apenas fechei as tags nos lugares corretos, e organizei basicamente o código.

Veja como ficou:

**OBS:** Aqui no snippet do StackOverflow ele fica meio quebrado pq a largura do box é pequena. Mas mande exibir em "Página toda" para ver melhor como fica. Ou então vc vai ter que usar os `@media` para tratar seu formulário em telas pequenas.

```css
.dados_principais {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dados_principais' style='text-align: center;margin-top: 4px;border: 1px solid red;background-color:#dcdcdc;'>
    <b>
        <span style='font-style: italic; font-family: arial;'>Teste de robos</span>
    </b>
    <div style='width:100%;text-align: left;'>
        <div class='dados_principais' style='text-align: left;width:17%; margin-top: -1px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff; '>
            <div style='padding-left:3px; float:left; font-size: 9px;  '>1º Data</div>
            <div style='padding-left:3px;'>
                <span>". $data_inicio_ensaio ."</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='dados_principais' style='width:41%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
            <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura </div>
            <span style='visibility:hidden;'>.</span>
        </div>

        <div class='dados_principais' style='border: 1px solid black;width:41.50%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
            <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura </div>
            <span style='visibility:hidden;'>.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style='width:100%;text-align: left; margin-top: -1px;border: 1px solid blue;'>
        <div class='dados_principais' style='border: 1px solid black;width:17%; margin-top: -1px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff; '>
            <div style='padding-left:3px; float:left; font-size: 9px;  '>2º Data</div>
            <div style='padding-left:3px;'>
                <span>". $data_inicio_ensaio2 ."</span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class='dados_principais' style='width:39%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
            <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura</div>
            <div style='padding-left:3px;'>
                <span style='visibility:hidden;'>.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='dados_principais' style='border: 1px solid black;width:39%; margin-top: 0px;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;'>
            <div style='padding-left:2px;  float:left; font-size: 9px;'>Assinatura </div>
            <div style='padding-left:3px;'>
                <span style='visibility:hidden;'>.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, foi isto mesmo, problemas com abertura e fechamento de tag.

Comment: @PauloGalego que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Comment: Verdade!! Esta marcada. Obrigado